# Persistent Entity in spring-boot Controller

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am developing an `spring-boot` application using `sping-data` and `Hibernate`. I have created some Entities which have associations like `OneToMany` or `ManyToMany` like:

```
@Entity
public class Department {

@OneToMany(mappedBy="department", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Employee> employees;

public void addEmployee(Employee emp) {
  emp.setDepartment(this);
  employees.add(emp);
}

}
```

`FetchType` of `OneToMany` is by default `LAZY` either in `JPA` or in `Hibernate`. I load the Entity `Department` using within a `Transactional` `Service` using a method of `JpaRepository` as:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DepartmentService {

DepartmentRepository repo;

public Department findById(Long id) {
  return repo.findOne(id);
}

}

public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository {

}
```

When I load the Entity in a class annotated with `@Controller` in a `POST` or `GET` method as:

```
public class DepartmentController {

DepartmentService departmentService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/departments/{did}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String update() {
 Department dep = departmentService.findById(did);
 dep.add(new Employee());

  ...

}

}
```

then I have access to the associations and I can add `Employees` to `Department`. The Entity seems namely to be `persistent` and not `detached`.
When I do the same in a `Unit Test`, then the Entity `Department` is `detached` and I get `LazyInitializationException`, unless I annotate the `Unit Test` class with `@Transactional`. I have not set `OpenSessionInViewFilter` in `Spring / Hibenate` configuration. Why are the Entities in the `Controller` persistent?

Comment: i would say because of your `@Transactional` in your service class. as far as i know you have to set the `@Transactional` for your test so they work properly, but the test won't persist any data

Comment: I believe Spring Boot applies Open Session by default.

Comment: The behavout in Unit Test is expected and it does not wonder me, since the Entities are detached as expected after the transaction having completed. The unexpected behavour is in the Controller and this is the cause and the target of my question. Why are they persistent while any transaction is not executed?